# Decorating A Method In ASP.NET?

Tags: decorator

Me again..  I hear the phrase 'decorating / decorate' a method being thrown about a lot in tutorials I have read / watched.  But I just don't understand what it means AND what it actually does??  Can anyone point me in the direction of some information on beginning to use them (Very novice tutorial would be good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET does not have "decorators" but it does have attributes.  Developers often use the word "decorate" to indicate the usage of attributes.  [Here is a good article explaining how they work and how to use them.](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1044870.html)

Comment: Fantastic thanks for the link, just what I was looking for - This site is fantastic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dotnetattributes.aspx) for an introduction and tutorial.

To Decorate in .NET you use attributes which act as metadata that is available to you at runtime which helps describe the items in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the Decorator design pattern there is a very clear example on [dofactory.com](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx).

Hope this helps